# Access params in GrailsUserDetailsService

Tags: grails, spring-security

How can I access params in **GrailsUserDetailsService**? I have a class implementing **GrailsUserDetailsService**, and I want to be able to access the parameters in the POST call to

```
website.com/j_security_check.
```

Comment: can you post your code here? The question is not properly framed..

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use `RequestContextHolder`:

```
import org.springframework.web.context.request.RequestContextHolder

def params = RequestContextHolder.requestAttributes.params
```